# What events we can use other than uploadfinished for lightning-file-upload?

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload

I need to have a way to display wait indicator/spinner when user has selected a file and till the time below pop comes? When selecting large size files it is taking time and seems confusing to end user on what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are no other published events. You may want to log a bug/feature request on the [Idea Exchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).

Comment: any suggestion on how i can attempt to achieve this?